# JS onload change innerHTML through Xpath

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I am using `onload` to try to change a button inneHTML text.
Is there a way to change the text through xPath ?

my path looks like this: `//*[@id="submission26"]/form/div/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]`

So what i want to do is something like this

```
<img src"#" onload="document.getElemnent(Path).innerHTML = 'test' " />
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: jQuery supports basic xPath expressions

Answer (score 0):

Not as such.

XPath is a tool to find nodes in a DOM. Nothing more.

Any API (you didn't say which one you were using) that allows you to use XPath is likely to have functions for manipulating those nodes once you have found them (otherwise it wouldn't be useful) but that isn't a feature of XPath itself.